# Multi language support in application

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a little tool which also features a GUI. I want to offer different languages in the interface. That's why I think about writing all the strings in a file for each language and read the data while creating the gui. I'm worried about that this could takes alot of memory and decreasing performance. 
Is there a good way to implement this?

Pseudocode example:

```
language_file = open(path)
title = language_file.title
text = language_file.text
button_text = language_file.btntext

window = tk.Tk()
la_title = tk.Label(window, text=title)
la_text  = tk.Label(window, text=text)
btn = tk.Button(window, text=button_text, command=close_window)
```

Comment: Questions with a snippet of input and expected output get better responses than text explanation. Can you paste snippet of your data & expected output? (you can paste them in HTML snippets)

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think Performance should't be a Problem. Because of this it may help editing your Topic to something like Multi language support in application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Find a proper file Format.

Some Formats are better suited than others. You Need something where you can define something like a label and for each language the correpsonding value. You could try the csv Format.

### 2. Loading the data into a python object

When you have created your file with all your data you can load it at the start of your program into a python object. this shouldn't take too Long when your file isn't huge and I mean huge. You open the file and load in some python opject to work with it.

### 3. Creating a proper python object.

What you want is something like a dictionary. You have a label which is the key and a value dependent on the selected language. So you could either have for each language a dictionary. or a more nested ditionary.
For better Access I would create a class to handle all this.

Possible Things that can make Things easier. (I will expand this part later on. And add more details)

You could:

- Override the `__getattr__` method so you can write: `Language.header`
- Extend the `__dict__` of the the class with the language dictionary: `Language.header` is possible
- write a function: `Language.get_text("Header")` or `Language.get_text("Header", "english")` or ...

### Dictionary example (expanding `__dict__`)

```
class Language:

    def __init__(self, texts):
        self.texts = Texts
        print(dir(self)) # just for debug
        # Magic part
        self.__dict__.update(self.texts)
        print(dir(self)) # just for debug. Note the last entries

    @staticmethod
    def from_file(path, language):
        # comment the open part out if you just want to test this example without a file
        with open(path, r) as f:
             pass # Read content. Get all words of language
        texts = {"header": "My header", "label_username": "Username"}
        return Language(texts)

l = Language.from_file("Some path to a file", "English")
print(l.header)
print(l.label_username)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The last method looks quit simple for me. The first one looks also manageable, but I don't know how to implement the second one. What's the difference between the first and the second one?

EDIT: Can you give me a short example how the object should look like? Should I use subclasses?

Comment: I added an example for the `__dict__`. It Needs some understanding what dunder methods are and is advanced python, but this is why I love python